# Normalized audio cross corelation

Tags: audio, cross-correlation, normalization

I'm trying to cross corelate two audio files to see where they line up.
In scipy im doing: `correlation = correlate(audio1, audio2, mode='full')`

Given the graph below it looks like the songs line up at the peak around 2.5. However, the true point where the songs line up is a bit before 1. I think the issue is that a song is repetitive and since the true "line up" happens while only the first bit of audio 2 has overlapped with audio 1 it's not being weighed as highly.

I was wondering if there's a way to normalize a cross corelation such that portions where audio 2 is fully inside audio aren't given more weight.

I tried normalizing this way:

```
correlation = correlate(audio1, audio2, mode='full')
overlap_counts = [min(i + 1, len(audio1), len(audio2), len(audio1) + len(audio2) - i - 1) for i in range(len(correlation))]
normalized_correlation = correlation / overlap_counts  # element-wise division
```

But this led to the result being whatever was at the start of the correlation array.

Would greatly appreciate any help here!

[image]

Comment: I think the idea to normalize a cross-correlation is to form a triangle window that's the same length as the cross-correlation sequence, and then element-wise divide the cross-correlation by the triangular window.

Comment: Hey @Baddioes thanks for the reply!

but isnt this:
```
correlation = correlate(audio1, audio2, mode='full')
overlap_counts = [min(i + 1, len(audio1), len(audio2), len(audio1) + len(audio2) - i - 1) for i in range(len(correlation))]
normalized_correlation = correlation / overlap_counts  # element-wise division
```
A tringle normalization? I've tried using numpy to see if the issue was numerical stability but got the same result.

With nomalization it gives me the frame basically right at the start.

Comment: Are there other popular normalization techniques? With noisy audio (what we're dealing with) it looks like triangle cross corelation gives an unfair advantage to the start of the songs

Comment: See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xcorr.html for more ideas on normalization. You might try them if you keep getting weird results. I don't know if overlap_counts will spit out a triangle or not, I'd have to see a plot of it, but my thought is that it would plateau. I'd just use scipy.signal.windows.triang. There is also a normalized cross correlation that is different than a normalizing a cross correlation. See normxcorr2() in the matlab documentation. Maybe you can find a 1D version of that in Python.

Comment: Cool will look into it, thanks!